# Android global variable

Tags: android, global-variables

How can I create global variable keep remain values around the life cycle of the application regardless which activity running.

Comment: And why we should use set and get (Jeff Gilfelt's asnwer)?! Why we just set value directly to variable? like this: public volatile static String x; and to set value : GeneralClass.x = value;

Answer (score 585, accepted):

You can extend the base `android.app.Application` class and add member variables like so:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private String someVariable;

    public String getSomeVariable() {
        return someVariable;
    }

    public void setSomeVariable(String someVariable) {
        this.someVariable = someVariable;
    }
}
```

In your android manifest you must declare the class implementing android.app.Application (add the `android:name=".MyApplication"` attribute to the existing application tag):

```
<application 
  android:name=".MyApplication" 
  android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Then in your activities you can get and set the variable like so:

```
// set
((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).setSomeVariable("foo");

// get
String s = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).getSomeVariable();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working for me. Please confirm that after this we'll have two <application> tags in manifest. Right? Because at some places I heard people saying that we have to add this to existing application tag. Please help !!

Comment: @AdilMalik You have to add the android:name tag to the existing application tag

Comment: This is not working when we toggle the USB mass storage mode. The MyApplication gets destroyed. Any help in this situation?

Comment: I am still having problems. my global class is called `GlobalObjects` and my manifest has the following : `    <application
        android:name="GlobalObjects"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >`

Comment: Just bumping into an old thread, how safe is this when using to store Username and Password?

Comment: where do I have to define that MyApplication class?

Comment: @Philip You just need it in your `src` directory, for example: `src/com/insightemissions/trak/MyApplication.java`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the benefit of keeping the variable private and using a getter/setter, vs making it public?

Comment: Why not just create a class with public static fields without any need to access a context?

Comment: This should not be correct answer as it can lead to unpredicted behavior and to NPE due to memory cleanup. http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/

Comment: Thank you! and the same with an array??

Comment: I have set my up the globals but when i try to set them im getting an error with getApplication when im trying to set the global. Any ideas why?

Comment: I agree with  @bakua. We should not expect that, when ever, our app is in background is not killed when android is short of memory.

Comment: @Jeff Gilfelt I am having a problem on this.getApplication() it's just red.

Comment: Another issue that arises with this is if you need MultiDex support, your application needs to be named with:          android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" .  So you cannot create your own class.  And a lot of apps need this nowadays.

Comment: in this situation is using a `private` variable and public functions better than merely using a public variable?

Comment: Just to let you know, read carefully @bakua 's answer, as I did actually get null pointer exceptions (very rarely and not debuggable) because of that. I was putting some stuff in application's Companion object...

Answer (score 44):

You can use a `Singleton Pattern` like this:

```
package com.ramps;

public class MyProperties {
private static MyProperties mInstance= null;

public int someValueIWantToKeep;

protected MyProperties(){}

public static synchronized MyProperties getInstance() {
        if(null == mInstance){
            mInstance = new MyProperties();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

In your application you can access your singleton in this way:

```
MyProperties.getInstance().someValueIWantToKeep
```

Comment: What if activity paused and user started another application and during that memeory was low thats why android removed this static object when user resume application and found this static reference null ???

Comment: Good point. You could use onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) from one of your activities to save the state of your singleton. 
Another solution would be to implement persistent DAO basing on SharedPreferences. In this case your data would be always kept in persistent memory.

Comment: A static is useless across activities in separate processes.

Comment: this wont work if your instance is garbage collected. so the block of code if(null == mInstance){
      mInstance = new MyProperties();
     } will work and new instance will be returned, which will reset the properties

Comment: @LalithB According to your last comment, so is singleton useless all the time?!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Singleton is not useless its just that we need to know what to keep inside the Singleton, If we keep huge bitmap array's or some collections then it may become dangerous. Keep note of what you keep inside the Singleton.

Comment: I know I am a bit late but for future readers, we can store values in SharedPreferences, SQLLite Database, or An Internal memory file. These all will have data persistence even if the application is closed.

Comment: @powernit: My thoughts exactly. Not sure why folks frequently travel down this path.

Answer (score 17):

This global variable works for my project:

```
public class Global {
    public static int ivar1, ivar2;
    public static String svar1, svar2;
    public static int[] myarray1 = new int[10];
}


//  How to use other or many activity
Global.ivar1 = 10;

int i = Global.ivar1;
```

Comment: But then how do you pass it to multiple activities?

Comment: These statics (at least string and array) may get nulled out by android VM when application is suspended and device has low memory.

Comment: @mahasam i dont think static should be the right way... if its only activities, it should be via Application context. Else a singleton way as given in other answers above. static will strongly couple the code, and also reduces the testability

Answer (score 15):

You could use application preferences. They are accessible from any activity or piece of code as long as you pass on the Context object, and they are private to the application that uses them, so you don't need to worry about exposing application specific values, unless you deal with routed devices. Even so, you could use hashing or encryption schemes to save the values. Also, these preferences are stored from an application run to the next.
[Here](https://github.com/codesorcerers/aegis-shield/blob/master/src/com/googlecode/aegisshield/utils/app/ApplicationPreferenceManager.java) is some code examples that you can look at.

Comment: I've updated the link. Project was hosted on Google Code and as we know that was closed down. The link is from Github.

Answer (score 12):

Use SharedPreferences to store and retrieve global variables.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String userid = preferences.getString("userid", null);
```

Comment: Considering the reliability, privacy and inaccessibility to other applications, this should be upvoted.

Comment: they want the variable for the lifecycle. shared preference is saved even if the application is killed.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few different ways you can achieve what you are asking for.

**1.) Extend the application class and instantiate your controller and model objects there.**

```
public class FavoriteColorsApplication extends Application {

    private static FavoriteColorsApplication application;
    private FavoriteColorsService service;

    public FavoriteColorsApplication getInstance() {
        return application;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        application = this;
        application.initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        service = new FavoriteColorsService();
    }

    public FavoriteColorsService getService() {
        return service;
    }

}
```

Then you can call the your singleton from your custom Application object at any time:

```
public class FavoriteColorsActivity extends Activity {

private FavoriteColorsService service = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private List<String> favoriteColors = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite_colors);

    service = ((FavoriteColorsApplication) getApplication()).getService();
    favoriteColors = service.findAllColors();

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favoriteColorsListView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.favorite_colors_list_item,
            favoriteColors);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**2.) You can have your controller just create a singleton instance of itself:**

```
public class Controller {
    private static final String TAG = "Controller";
    private static sController sController;
    private Dao mDao;

    private Controller() {
        mDao = new Dao();    
    }

    public static Controller create() {
        if (sController == null) {
            sController = new Controller();
        }
        return sController;
    }
}
```

Then you can just call the create method from any Activity or Fragment and it will create a new controller if one doesn't already exist, otherwise it will return the preexisting controller.

**3.) Finally, there is a slick framework created at Square which provides you dependency injection within Android. It is called [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/). I won't go into how to use it here, but it is very slick if you need that sort of thing.**

I hope I gave enough detail in regards to how you can do what you are hoping for.

Answer (score 6):

Try Like This:

Create a shared data class:

**SharedData.java**

```
import android.app.Application;

/**
 * Created by kundan on 6/23/2015.
 */
public class Globals {


    private static Globals instance = new Globals();

    // Getter-Setters
    public static Globals getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static void setInstance(Globals instance) {
        Globals.instance = instance;
    }

    private String notification_index;


    private Globals() {

    }


    public String getValue() {
        return notification_index;
    }


    public void setValue(String notification_index) {
        this.notification_index = notification_index;
    }



}
```

Declared/Initiaze an instance of class globally in those classes where you want to set/get data (using this code before `onCreate()` method):-

```
Globals sharedData = Globals.getInstance();
```

Set data:

```
sharedData.setValue("kundan");
```

Get data:

```
String n = sharedData.getValue();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a `Global Class` like this:

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application{

    private String name;
    private String email;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String aName) {
        name = aName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String aEmail) {
        email = aEmail;
    }
}
```

Then define it in the manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.globalvariable.GlobalClass" ....
```

Now you can set values to global variable like this:

```
final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
globalVariable.setName("Android Example context variable");
```

You can get those values like this:

```
final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
final String name  = globalVariable.getName();
```

Please find complete example from this blog
[Global Variables](https://androidexample.com/Global_Variable_Or_Application_Context_Variable_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=114&aaid=136)

Comment: if i write in activity "final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();"  get the exception like cannot be cast to application.Global .

Comment: It's not a very good approach, because then you will need the Context in order to get the ApplicationContext every time.

Answer (score 4):

```
// My Class Global Variables  Save File Global.Java
public class Global {
    public static int myVi; 
    public static String myVs;
}

// How to used on many Activity

Global.myVi = 12;
Global.myVs = "my number";
........
........
........
int i;
int s;
i = Global.myVi;
s = Global.myVs + " is " + Global.myVi;
```

Comment: Why you are posting two answer in the same question? You can edit it to one.

Answer (score 4):

I checked for similar answer, but those given here don't fit my needs.
I find something that, from my point of view, is what you're looking for. The only possible black point is a security matter (or maybe not) since I don't know about security.

I suggest using Interface (no need to use Class with constructor and so...), since you only have to create something like :

```
public interface ActivityClass {

    public static final String MYSTRING_1 = "STRING";

    public static final int MYINT_1 = 1;

}
```

Then you can access everywhere within your classes by using the following:

```
int myInt = ActivityClass.MYINT_1;
String myString = ActivityClass.MYSTRING_1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically this does not answer the question, but I would recommend using the Room database instead of any global variable. 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html
Even if you are 'only' needing to store a global variable and it's no big deal and what not, but using the Room database is the most elegant, native and well supported way of keeping values around the life cycle of the activity. 
It will help to prevent many issues, especially integrity of data. 
I understand that database and global variable are different but please use Room for the sake of code maintenance, app stability and data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you should declare the variables that you need to keep alive that haven't been clear by Garbage Collector or Unload by OS in file .so
To do it, you must code by C/C++ and compile to .so lib file and load it in your MainActivity.

Comment: Native code is a painful way to hold data in RAM, and do so no better than Java `static` variables.

Comment: I don't see the point of this approach. Can you elaborate in which case this is a good idea?

Answer (score -1):

```
import android.app.Application;

public class Globals extends Application
{
    private static Globals instance = null;
    private static int RecentCompaignID;
    private static int EmailClick;
    private static String LoginPassword;
    static String loginMemberID;
    private static String CompaignName = "";
    private static int listget=0;
    //MailingDetails
    private static String FromEmailadd="";
    private static String FromName="";
    private static String ReplyEmailAdd="";
    private static String CompaignSubject="";
    private static int TempId=0;
    private static int ListIds=0;

    private static String HTMLContent="";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static Globals getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    public void setRecentCompaignID(int objRecentCompaignID)
    {
        RecentCompaignID = objRecentCompaignID;
    }

    public int getRecentCompaignID() 
    {
        return RecentCompaignID;
    }

    public void setLoginMemberID(String objloginMemberID) 
    {
        loginMemberID = objloginMemberID;
    }

    public String getLoginMemberID() 
    {
        return loginMemberID;
    }

    public void setLoginMemberPassword(String objLoginPassword)
    {
        LoginPassword = objLoginPassword;
    }

    public String getLoginMemberPassword()
    {
        return LoginPassword;
    }

    public void setEmailclick(int id)
    {
        EmailClick = id;
    }

    public int getEmailClick() 
    {
        return EmailClick;
    }
    public void setCompaignName(String objCompaignName)
    {
        CompaignName=objCompaignName;
    }
    public String getCompaignName()
    {
        return CompaignName;
    }
    public void setlistgetvalue(int objlistget)
    {
        listget=objlistget;
    }
    public int getlistvalue()
    {
        return listget;
    }
    public void setCompaignSubject(String objCompaignSubject)
    {
         CompaignSubject=objCompaignSubject;
    }
    public String getCompaignSubject()
    {
        return CompaignSubject;
    }
    public void setHTMLContent(String objHTMLContent)
    {
        HTMLContent=objHTMLContent;
    }
    public String getHTMLContent()
    {
        return HTMLContent;
    }
    public void setListIds(int objListIds)
    {
        ListIds=objListIds;
    }
    public int getListIds()
    {
        return ListIds;
    }
    public void setReplyEmailAdd(String objReplyEmailAdd)
    {
        ReplyEmailAdd=objReplyEmailAdd;
    }
    public String getReplyEmailAdd()
    {
        return ReplyEmailAdd;
    }
    public void setFromName(String objFromName)
    {
        FromName=objFromName;
    }
    public String getFromName()
    {
        return FromName;
    }
    public void setFromEmailadd(String objFromEmailadd)
    {
        FromEmailadd=objFromEmailadd;
    }
    public String getFromEmailadd()
    {
        return FromEmailadd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Easy!!!!

Those variable you wanna access as global variable, you can declare them as static variables. And now, you can access those variables by using

classname.variablename;

```
public class MyProperties {
private static MyProperties mInstance= null;

static int someValueIWantToKeep;

protected MyProperties(){}

public static synchronized MyProperties getInstance(){
    if(null == mInstance){
        mInstance = new MyProperties();
    }
    return mInstance;
}
```

}

MyProperites.someValueIWantToKeep;

Thats It! ;)

Comment: not sure why it was downvoted so much; comparing with some other net-upvoted answers i see that this correctly (iirc) uses `synchronized` on the static `getInstance()` whereas others do not. upvoted accordingly.

Comment: Because it copied from an answer above.