# Global Variable with extended Application Class

Tags: android, global-variables

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable/) but when i set the variable im getting an error: `03-28 09:01:36.492: WARN/System.err(706): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application`

What is this? I added the `<application android:name="MyApplication" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">`
 after i close the . If i do it before the close its also not working.

EDIT: Okay it was because i have two times Application. Now i added it to the Application which was created by eclipse but it wants now permissions?!

EDIT2: Got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem due to duplicate Application file is not solved completely. Remove the file from the project completely. Then go to manifest file, Application Tab. Confirm that the Name field is empty. Add the name of your application file there and click on the link. This will create the application file again. Hope this helps.