# Android Passing BluetoothSocket to the next Activity

Tags: android, object

After connecting to the bluetooth, I need the child to send data out through that socket. But how do I get the socket over to the childActivity?

Comment: Why do you want to switch to another activity? And why do you send data on the UI Thread?

Comment: I have 2 different design of UI that need to send out data through the socket. Therefore I need to pass the socket over.

Comment: Or is there a way that I can call the write method in the main activity from the sub activity?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best design, but what I did here and it worked on my simple application was to have the bluetooth connection (the socket) as a "global variable", a variable of my main application (the class which extends the `Application` class).

In that way all my activities can get it and set it.

For doubts on how to set/get a global variable on such way, refer to [Android global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable)