# how to use same logout function to all the activity in the application?

Tags: android

In my application i have logout option on the header xml file and the functionality occurred related activity i want to use same functionality to all the page in my android application without reputation.
how to do this work?.

Answer (score 0):

[use application context for all the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `<incude></include>` feature of android to merge your Header layout in all othe layout.