# How can I prevent an IllegalStateException when I try to reuse a global variable?

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

I have an activity which gets a page from the web and then parses it to a TableLayout that is inside a ScrollView.

Then I save the ScrollView into a global variable just like its described by Jeff Gilfelt in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable/7838948#7838948).

After this I leave my activity and enter it again and I check if there is a saved ScrollView in the global variable, and if there is I try to set it via setContentView().

The problem is that I get an IllegalStateException on the `setContentView(savedScrollView);` call.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Dev questions are off-topic here; migrating to [SO].

Comment: Can you please post the Logcat output

Comment: shouldn't you call removeView at some point before calling setContentView for the second time?

Answer (score 0):

When activity is resumed,  chances are good that it is still configured and 
does not need view setting.  You shall set content view in onCreate() - not in onResume()