# Android multiple <application> in one androidmanifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am using 
[Android global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable) 
example.

How do I add another "application" tag in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filec), only **one** application tag can be inserted in the manifest.

Quote from doc:

> "Only the *manifest* and *application* elements are required, they each must be present and can occur only once."

If you're following the example at the given link, just add the `android:name` and `android:label` XML element to your current application tag and it'll work just fine.

Example of my application tag in an application I'm developing at the moment:

```
<application
    android:name=".Globals"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Globals is my application class.

Comment: OK. Thanks. So what will be the solution if I have to add a class extends from Application to add application global variables?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question was asked a long time ago but using Android Studio 3.0 and higher, I came across the same problem and did not find anything online that helped.

After a lot of research and my own testing, I found out how to successfully implement two or more classes that both extend `android.app.Application` into the Manifest's `<Application/>`.

**First Class File:**

```
public abstract class MyClass1 extends Application {

    // ...
}
```

**Second Class File:**

```
public class MyClass2 extends MyClass1 {

    // ...
}
```

**Manifest File:**

```
<application

    android:name="com.mydomain.myapp.MyClass2">

    <!-- Rest of code here... -->

</application>
```

Comment: This worked for me, also had to add on highest priority manifest the following tag. tools:node="merge". In my use-case, I was including a library created by be with dependency injection, that needed an Application. Then on main App, I extended the lib Application as mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

[how to handle multiple application classes in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001644/how-to-handle-multiple-application-classes-in-android)

When a library is already extending the "Applicaton" class just do the following

```
class lib1 extend Application {
...
}

class lib2 extend lib1{
...
}
```

in the manifest ->  `<application android:name = "package.lib2".....`