# how to handle multiple application classes in android

Tags: android, manifest

I am developing a native android application, in which I am trying to use **2 open-source libraries**. Problem is **both the libraries are using Application Class** in their respective libraries. They are registering these classes in their respective source code in manifest file using **"android:name" under the application tag**.
Question is **how to handle such a scenario**, since as we know, **only ONE  tag can be used inside manifest file**. 
Can we register/instantiate the Application Class in the code, so that we mention only ONE library in  tag and the second using code/pragmatically.
OR are there any other alternatives. 
Please share your comments/suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your scenario is like "ApplicationLib1 extends Application" , "ApplicationLib2 extends Application" and "YourApplication extends Application" ?

Comment: You need to implement Multilevel inheritance to resolve this scenario.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia And what we can do if libraries were jar?! In this case we can't write something like this: public Lib2Application extends Lib1Application!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to implement Multilevel inheritance to resolve this scenario.

**This is your scenario**

```
public Lib1Application extends Application{

}

public Lib2Application extends Application{

}

public YourApplication extends Application{

}
```

**How to resolve this?**

```
public Lib1Application extends Application{

    }

    public Lib2Application extends Lib1Application{

    }

    public YourApplication extends Lib2Application{

    }
```

**finally in mainfest.xml**

```
<application
        android:name="com.your.packagename.YourApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ijoomer_luncher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
 >
```

Comment: how can i use lib2Application class.. please give me an example?

Comment: Some times you will need to implement it in several places in The Manifest:
<application
        android:name="com.example.MyAppClass"
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MyAppClass"
            android:configChanges="locale"
            android:label="MyAppClass" >
            <action android:name="com.example.MyAppClass" />
        </activity>

Comment: And what we can do if libraries were jar?! In this case we can't write something like this: public Lib2Application extends Lib1Application !

Comment: @ Mr.Hyde your point is very nice. Need some more steps to make it work even it is inside .jar files. Just create a separate question and get me the link for that.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452509

Answer (score 1):

Only the manifest and application elements are required, they each must be present and can occur only once. Most of the others can occur many times or not at all — although at least some of them must be present for the manifest to accomplish anything meaningful.
See this link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filec