# How to implement two application classes in my manifest

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Lets say i have a listview as my main activity.On clicking an item it opens up a second activity.On clicking a button it opens a custom listview using volley library from this tutorial if you are following(http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)
However on clicking the button in the second activity to open my listview with volley,my app stops.
The problem i figured started in the manifest as i'll post below.
I have two Application classes as i am using Parse push notification library.But however only one application can be declared to open on startup in the manifest.So i implemented the answer on this question([how to handle multiple application classes in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001644/how-to-handle-multiple-application-classes-in-android)) .It was after this that my app kept stopping when opening the third activity.
So please help me achieve this.Thanks in advance.

Manifest snippet

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.stevekamau.snapt"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
 
<application
    android:name="com.stevekamau.snapt.ParseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        
   </activity>
..............</activity>
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
 
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
         <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
              
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I modified the AppController class from here(http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/ ) to extend ParseApplication

```js
public class AppController extends ParseApplication {
  
    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
 
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
 
    private static AppController mInstance;
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }
 
    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
 
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }
 
        return mRequestQueue;
    }
 
    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }
 
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
 
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
 
    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more code please let me know.

```
log cat:
11-21 16:20:29.916: E/Trace(26640): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-21 16:20:29.936: W/dalvikvm(26640): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
11-21 16:20:30.046: W/System.err(26640): Invalid int: ""
11-21 16:20:30.386: I/Adreno200-EGL(26640): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
11-21 16:20:30.386: I/Adreno200-EGL(26640): Build Date: 10/26/12 Fri
11-21 16:20:30.386: I/Adreno200-EGL(26640): Local Branch: 
11-21 16:20:30.386: I/Adreno200-EGL(26640): Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
11-21 16:20:30.386: I/Adreno200-EGL(26640): Local Patches: NONE
11-21 16:20:30.386: I/Adreno200-EGL(26640): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010 +  NOTHING
11-21 16:20:37.636: W/dalvikvm(26640): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e08438)
11-21 16:20:49.016: E/Trace(26711): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-21 16:20:49.036: W/dalvikvm(26711): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
11-21 16:20:49.096: W/System.err(26711): Invalid int: ""
```

Comment: Add your logcat error!

Comment: It may also be beneficial to add the exception from logcat.

Comment: I have included log cat in my edit

Comment: androidhive samples are bad ... there is no need for extending Application class for using the volley ... class with static metods: `getImageLoader(Context appContext)`  and `getRequestQueue(Context appContext)` should be enough

Comment: From their sample tutorials they say:"The best way to maintain volley core objects and request queue is, making them global by creating a singleton class which extends Application object."

Comment: hehe thats why i wrote **androidhive samples are bad**. There is too many bad code practices there (and i'm not only talking about this sample but their samples at all)

Comment: from documentation: `There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when first constructing the singleton.`

Comment: @Selvin,i get you.What do you suggest i do to implement the above?

Comment: in the way as I stated in my previous comment ...

Comment: Howcome you cannot have both Parse and Volley in the same Application class? As far as I know, Parse is just a few lines of initiation inside onCreate

Comment: @Selvin i'm getting error markers in the code.I am not implementing it in the right way.If you could refer me to somewhere i can check out more code i'd highly appreciate.

Comment: @cYrixmorten let me try that now.i see your point

Comment: @cYrixmorten It has worked.Thanks alot guys.Appreciate it much.