# how to Add two android:name attributes to Application tag in Manifest file?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-volley

My Android application requires two application classes,one is volley AppController and another one is Analytics class.I am confused how to add both at a time.please help me and get me out of this.

Comment: you can not add `android:name` twice. you will get `Duplicate attribute name` error.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Rustam....Is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: check my answer link how to handle multiple application classes in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your volley AppController class extend your Analytics application class. Then specify your volley AppController in your manifest.

Comment: Good stuff, please mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 9):

You need to implement Multilevel inheritance to resolve this scenario.

**This is your scenario**

```
public Lib1Application extends Application{

}

public Lib2Application extends Application{

}

public YourApplication extends Application{

}
```

**How to resolve this?**

```
public Lib1Application extends Application{

}

public Lib2Application extends Lib1Application{

}

public YourApplication extends Lib2Application{

}
```

**finally in mainfest.xml**

```
<application
        android:name="com.your.packagename.YourApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ijoomer_luncher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
 >
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Multilevel inheritance to resolve this scenario.

[how to handle multiple application classes in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001644/how-to-handle-multiple-application-classes-in-android)

Comment: Thanks @Rustam it looks NIce i will try it