# Multiple Applications in android manifest

Tags: java, android, acra, sugarorm, acralyzer

Am developing an app and using two libraries one is SugarORM for handling the databases and the other one is ACRA for bugs tracking.

my problem came when i needed to implement the ACRA , found that i need to declare it into the Manifest.xml in the Application tag.

SugarORM requires to be declared as an application in the manifest and so is ACRA, after some searching i found that the proposed solution is to have multilevel inheritance but could not figure how,

Since i need to build only one class extending the Application class and it's ACRA , SugarORM has the Application class ready built.

any help?

**UPDATE :**

After some research i found this

[how to handle multiple application classes in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001644/how-to-handle-multiple-application-classes-in-android)

which used multilevel inheritance

so i made the ACRA application extend the already existing SugarApp class

am still not sure if it works properly

Comment: Yeah this worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001644/how-to-handle-multiple-application-classes-in-android

Answer (score 1):

After reading the setup instructions for both of them, ACRA seems to only need the internet permission to be set up in the manifest. The name should just be the package/name your app is using