# Multiple Application Classes in one Project

Tags: android, class, manifest

To save some preferences I use the class [EasyPreferences](https://github.com/Pixplicity/EasyPreferences) .
Because of that library I need a second Class that extends Application.

To add it to the manifest I have found here a clever [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001644/how-to-handle-multiple-application-classes-in-android). 
So easy. So simple.

But for some reason it does not work for me.

My first application class:

```
package com.stack.overflow.network;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.pixplicity.easyprefs.library.Prefs;

public class NetworkController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = NetworkController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    //LruBitmapCache mLruBitmapCache;

    private static NetworkController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized NetworkController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    /*
    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            getLruBitmapCache();
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, mLruBitmapCache);
        }

        return this.mImageLoader;
    }*/
/*
    public LruBitmapCache getLruBitmapCache() {
        if (mLruBitmapCache == null)
            mLruBitmapCache = new LruBitmapCache();
        return this.mLruBitmapCache;
    } */

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

}
```

The second application class:

```
package com.stack.overflow.HelperClasses.SharedPreferences;

import com.stack.network.NetworkController;

public class PrefsApplication extends NetworkController {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


 new Prefs.Builder()
                .setContext(getApplicationContext())
                .setMode(ContextWrapper.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .setPrefsName(getPackageName())
                .setUseDefaultSharedPreference(true)
                .build();
    }

}
```

When I move the Prefs.Builder() into the onCreate() Method of Network controller everything works fine. But not if it is kept in its own class PrefsApplication. I don't understand why.

In AndroidManifest.xml is the Class NetworkController named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need of that, Android your application can handle only 1 application class else you want multiple for that you have to extend B_Application class from A_Application class.

Comment: this is exactly what I do in the code below. And I do not get the mistake because the Prefs.Builder() code is never executed

Comment: which class you have added in android manifest at application tag.

Comment: android:name="com.stack.overflow.network.NetworkController"

Comment: add : PrefsApplication this one there.