# I have multiple classes which extend application class

Tags: android, android-layout

If I have two class of extended with Application Class. How do I handle the App? I have two Class. How do I manage the two Global Class in manifest. I have created two Module now I am integrating so it creating a problem for me.

Comment: Why do you need 2 classes like that?

Comment: In first class i have done Network parsing Work

Comment: in Second class i have done Cart Controller. Both should be Global so extended with Application class

Comment: Im not sure why do you have to devide into 2 classes, I think 2 activities can resolve almost issues. But please read this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001644/how-to-handle-multiple-application-classes-in-android

Comment: If two class can't be extended then how do i implement. or how do merge this two different class. because both have different functionality

Comment: i have done this process ! but it does effect anything and error is thrown

Comment: @PushpendraSingh could we take a look at the code?

Comment: you have to post your code so that we can advise you how you can merge it.

Answer (score 1):

> if i have two class of extended with Application Class. How do i Handle the App?

Have one subclass the other. Or merge them together. Or delete one. Or delete both.

> In first class i have done Network parsing Work. in Second class i have done Cart Controller. Both should be Global so extended with Application class

It is unclear if *either* of those things should be global in scope. Even if they should be global in scope, then *neither* of those things need to extend `Application`. Have them be standard Java singletons.

Answer (score 0):

Only the `<manifest>` and `<application>` elements are required.
**They each must be present and can occur only once.** Most of the other elements can occur many times or not at all. However, at least some of them must be present before the manifest file becomes useful.
If an element contains anything at all, it contains other elements. All of the values are set through attributes, not as character data within an element.

Elements at the same level are generally not ordered. For example, the `<activity>`, `<provider>`, and `<service>` elements can be intermixed in any sequence. There are two key exceptions to this rule:

An `<activity-alias>` element must follow the `<activity>` for which it is an alias.
The `<application>` element must be the last element inside the  element. In other words, the `</application>` closing tag must appear immediately before the `</manifest>` closing tag.