# "You uploaded an APK file whose AndroidManifest.xml contains multiple tag entries" error while uploading to Google Play

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, google-play, xamarin

I'm trying to upload my first app to Google play, but when I do I get this error

"You uploaded an APK file whose AndroidManifest.xml contains multiple tag entries. There must be only one."

I am using Xamarin for Android using Visual Studio 2010.

So if anyone knows whats causing this or how I can fix this error, please let me know!

This is my AndroidManifest file after I decoded it (After Xamarin built it).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.app.pro"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="App" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name="mono.android.app.Application" android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:label="Pickup Lines List" android:name="App.ListViewLayout" />
        <activity android:label="App" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name="App.Main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:authorities="com.App.pro.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" android:initOrder="2147483647" />
    </application>
    <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your manifest file contains two `application` tags while you should only have one.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple `<application ../>` tags within your manifest. According to the [manifest documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) this is invalid:

**"Only the manifest and application elements are required, they each must be present and can occur only once**."

Combine the `<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />` application entry with the one above it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... />
    <application 
        android:label="App" 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:name="mono.android.app.Application" 
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        ...
    </application>
    ...
</manifest>
```

See:

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filec
2. [Android multiple <application> in one androidmanifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419955/android-multiple-application-in-one-androidmanifest)