# How to broadcast variable value and receive it?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I am making an application in which I want to broadcast variable value on button click.
At the same time I want to receive this value in other activity and display it.
How should I do the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like you can use a global variable , which can be used across activities.(Also answering some unasked questions ;) )

For the same, you can extend [android.app.Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class,

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state. You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created.

---

Example from [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1945297/977676),

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private String someVariable;

    public String getSomeVariable() {
        return someVariable;
    }

    public void setSomeVariable(String someVariable) {
        this.someVariable = someVariable;
    }
}
```

Then in your activities you can get and set the variable like so:

```
// set
((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).setSomeVariable("foo");

// get
String s = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).getSomeVariable();
```

---

As given in the example, *set* your variable from one activity (or button click whatever) and *get* that value in another activity.

Comment: Can't see how this is better then just to add an extra when opening the new activity. This will keep the variable in memory...

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
Create a custom intent in the sending activity (example: CurrentActivity):

```
public static final String RESTART_CHAT_POLLING_INTENT = "com.cleeqa.android.chat.restart.intent";
```

Broadcast it:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(RESTART_CHAT_POLLING_INTENT );
mContext.sendBroadcast(i);
```

Register a broadcastReceiver in the activity you want to receive (NewActivity):

```
BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(CurrentActivity.RESTART_CHAT_POLLING_INTENT);
registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
```

Receive the broadcast (Also in the NewActivity):

```
private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(CurrentActivity.RESTART_CHAT_POLLING_INTENT)) {

                //DO WHAT YOU WANT

            }
    }
```

**Option 2 (no need for broadcast receiver):**
onClick:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("PARAM", parameter);
startActivity(intent);
```

onCreate/onStart of the activity you want to receive (NewActivity):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            parameter = extras.getString("PARAM");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary for your application to broadcast the variable? if you simply wanted to pass a variable from current activity to a new activity, start the new activity from current by calling startActivityForResult and pass the variable as parameter.

if you don't want the new activity to send the results back to current activity use startActivity

Answer (score 1):

I think passing it using `intent.putExtra("PARAM", parameter);` and reading it with `getExtras()` is much easier and appropriate for what he needs to do!