# How can I make a global have a unique number?

Tags: java, android, global-variables

I wish to retrieve a unique number every time I start my program (from the internet) and to be able to have access to it in every class without passing it every time. Is this possible?
I believe this must be somehow standard as uniqueID and is used everyhere but I am new to Android and Java.

Comment: why do you want to retrieve it from the internet again? Is it not sufficient to generate a random number?

Comment: No it is the result of authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a previous solution that might be useful... [Android global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable)

Alternatively, you could declare a public static String, set the value of the String in the first class, and then each access to this String from other classes would return this same value.

For example...

**Class 1...**

```
public static String uniqueID;
uniqueID = <code_to_generate_random_value>;
```

**Class 2, 3, 4..., where you want to get the value that was already set...**

```
String uniqueID = Class1.uniqueID;
```

Comment: The question wasnot to generate a random number

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class:

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Comment: to access it "from anywhere", you can assign it to a static member in an existing class or create a holder class for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

you can use singleton pattern

create a class with desired name using singleton pattern

set the variable 'unique_id' to value which you get from internet or from uuid provider

use this classes singleton instance anywhere in your project and call unique_id's getter method