# Global variable extend application class

Tags: subclass, global, extends, android

So I am trying extend the base `Application` class and add member variables to create global variables like in this first solution of the link below.

[Android global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable)

This works if the member variable is a simple data type like a `String` or a `Boolean`.  But how would you do it for a more complex data type?  In my case i would like the member variable to be of type  `HashMap<String, Boolean>`.

I am setting three member variables in `onActivityResult()` (a boolean, a `String`, and a `HashMap<String, Boolean>`), and i am trying to access these member variables in the `onClick()` method of a button's `onClickListener`.  When i access the string and boolean variables their values are set appropriately.  However when i access the `HashMap<String, Boolean>` variable its value is set to '{}', an empty `HashMap`.  Is there some kind of `Serialization` that needs to happen with a complex data type?

I have also added an `ArrayList<Boolean>` as a member variable and when i accessed this variable in the `onclick()` method it was set correctly.  Possibly HashMaps must be set differently.  I'm not too sure are this point.

In the code below, I am just showing a stripped down version which only includes the `HashMap` member variable.

Here is the my subclass of `Application`

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
  private HashMap<String, Boolean> selectedContacts = null;

  public HashMap<String, Boolean> getSelectedContacts() {
    return this.selectedContacts;
  }

  public void setSelectedContacts(HashMap<String, Boolean> sc) {
    this.selectedContacts = sc;
  }
}
```

Below are the methods `onActivityResult()` and `onClick()` in my Messenger `Activity`.  In `onActivityResult()`, I set the private member variable of the MyApp Class.  In the `onClick()` method, I call the accessor method.

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

  switch (reqCode) {
    case R.integer.contact_manager:

      if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        Log.d(getString(R.string.debug_tag), "FAILURE");
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d(getString(R.string.debug_tag), "SUCCESS");

        MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplication());

        appState.setSelectedContacts((HashMap<String, Boolean>) data.getSerializableExtra("selectedContacts")); 
      }

      break;
   } 
}  


add_contact_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent i = new Intent(Messenger.this, ContactManager.class);

    MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplication());
    HashMap<String, Boolean> sc = appState.getSelectedContacts();   

    if (sc != null) {
      int totalContacts = sc.size();
      if(totalContacts > 0) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("selectedContacts",sc); 
        i.putExtras(bundle);
      } 
    }
    startActivityForResult(i, R.integer.contact_manager);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this issue.  In the `onActivityResult()` method, I was iterating through the `HashMap` like so:

```
Iterator<Entry<String, Boolean>> it = sc.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  HashMap.Entry pairs = (HashMap.Entry) it.next();
  String contactId = pairs.getKey().toString();
  boolean selected = (Boolean) pairs.getValue();
  if (selected) {
    selectedContactsText += getName(contactId) + ", ";
    Log.d("Messenger", getName(contactId) + " was selected");
    Log.d("Messenger", selectedContactsText + " is the text");
  }
  it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}
```

However i noticed the last statement of the while loop was in fact removing elements from the `HashMap`.  So I commented this line out and all works as intended.