# C# Sending Complex Data between Activities in Android

Tags: c#, android, object, serialization

I am using visual studio 2010 C# language and trying to send an object from one Android Activity to another,
I have failed to store the object in some globally place via Global Configuration and also failed in using Serialization  method

Some methods and function are not recognized and giving me : 
The type or namespace name 'extends' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I was following these articles

[Global variable extend application class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059733/global-variable-extend-application-class)
[How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)
http://savagelook.com/blog/android/android-extending-application-to-handle-global-configuration

if someone has another solution  please provide to me with a demo source code or tutorial  in C#  for 2 methods:Serialization and  using Global place, in order to achieve  my target and send object from one activity to another in Adnroid c# language

Comment: **extends** is a java key-word but not a c# one. are you trying to compile java sources with a c# compiler?

Comment: `extends` is a Java keyword and will not be recognized in C# where the equivalent is `:`. How does you setup for working with C# and Visual Studio look like? It is a quite unusual setup and certainly not recommended when you don't know much about Android development; then stay with Java and Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "extends" in .Net. The counterpart of .Net to the Java "extends" is ":".

For example (pseudo Java)

```
class A extends B
```

would be (pseudo C# as a .Net)

```
class A : B
```

Comment: do you have a complete coe for this?