# Cannot close android activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an application with an activity (activity1) that pauses when pressing a button, opening a new activity (activity2) that has two buttons: a menu button and a button to resume the activity1. Pressing the menu button that opens a new activity (activity3) that has a button to get out of the application but instead of closing, it goes back to activity1, restarting it.
How can I close the aplication or close the activity1 inside the activity 2 or 3?

Sorry my English.
thank you very much

Comment: Check it from here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3725042/1395259

Comment: You might be interested in reading this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle

Comment: I am going to tell you an answer i'm gonna regret. System.exit(0);

Comment: "System.exit(0)"--have heard somewhere that not a good practice to exit the Application.

Answer (score 1):

When you call your activity, call `finish();` straight after:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This will run your new activity, and close the old one in the process.

Comment: But I what to pause activity1 when I pass to activity2. And when I change from activity2 to activity3 I finish activity2. But activity1 is paused on background and I want to finish it when I try to System.exit();.

Comment: If you close activity 1, (and 2?) Then when you click the button to close activity 3 (`finish();`), the whole application will close, as there are no longer any activities on the stack. Or see @userSeven7s answer. Actually, yes. Follow userSeven7s answer, I missed that you wanted to resume activity1 in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pressing the menu button that opens a new activity (activity3) that has a   
button to get out of the application but instead of closing,   
it goes back to activity1,restarting it.
```

Closing a Activity from other activity?? **Not Possible.**
But you can achieve it(`manually`) by setting a **Global Variable**..

Like when you press **Exit Button** in `Activity-3`,set a **Global variable(int)**,say `"int exit"` and **call** `finish()` in `Activity 3`,this will land you in `Activity-2`..Now in the **OnResume Method** of the `Activity-2` and `Activity-1`,Go On to Check the value of the Global Variable,`if exit== 1`,call `finish()` there.else do nothing.

## Edit

**[Global Variable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059733/global-variable-extend-application-class)**

Comment: How can I set glogal variables with out obejects?

Comment: You can create a class that would extend the class Application..there you can Declare variables and use there Values any where in any Activity.

Comment: Could you give me some example please?

Answer (score 1):

- Use startactivityforResult to start your second activity.
- In second activity, when you press exit menu button, finish the activity with result code 1..
- In onActivityResult of first activity, check the result  code.. if its exit code(1) then call finish...

Comment: This ^^^.  Starting both activities from Activity1 would give you more control over what's happening.  It doesn't sound like you actually WANT the activities to stack so this would work well.

Comment: I'm not understanding the third step!

Comment: Check this link ...  http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html