# Accessing tabhost's JSONObject or JSONArray

Tags: android, json, tabs, arraylist, android-tabhost

All I am trying to do is have a JSONObject that can be accessible from children tabs, so that I can put info into it.

```
 public class Example extends TabActivity{
            private JSONObject testtt = new JSONObject();
        public void writeJSON(String key, String value) throws JSONException {
         testtt.put(key, value);
         }
        public String getJSON(){
            return testtt.toString();
        }
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.example);
                    //Creating the tabs and everything
                    //Is Here
     }
    }
```

I have next/prev buttons than navigate the tabs back and forth
one of the tabs:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
 //Pre-alertDialog.setmessage stuff here.
   alertDialog.setMessage(Example.this.getJSON());
// Example.this gives this error: No enclosing instance of the type Example is accessible in scope
}
```

I have tried a ton of alternative stuff, and have gotten to the point of asking for help (extremely rare for me).
Its also probably obvious that I am relatively new to android development.

EDIT:
when attempting global variable via Class extends Application{
[image: logcat edited]

Comment: I figured my own problem out...
I was adding an <application> to the manifest... when all I needed to do was add the name to the EXISTING <application> tag.

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is use an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) object: stick the JSON on a shared variable in the Application object and access it from there in your other Activities.

Comment: I tried that... got a force close (I added it as an application to the manifest too)

Comment: What's the crash error? Add the entire exception trace from logcat.

Comment: this might take a while... stupid me deleted all that code instead of commenting out.

Comment: logcat screenshot... it breaks at this line of code: Jason jason = (Jason)getApplicationContext();