# Using a class to store static data in Java?

Tags: java, android

Is it a bad idea creating a separate class and use it as a storage which consists only of static data variables?

I am currently developing an app for android, but the question is general for Java.

In case of android, I am moving across activities and I would like to store some global/static flags/varibles in that separate class and being able to access them from any activity I want.

PS. The data is required only for the session time.

Comment: For the lifetime of your app it is a good decision.
for longlife storage use the sharedpreferences or sqlite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, that's not a bad idea. You can use such type of a class in Android. But a small correction here. Instead of maintaining a class that holds static Data, you can make that class to extend Application class and use it store the data.

Here is a example,

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
        private int globalVariable=1;

        public int getGlobalVariable() {
                return globalVariable;
        }

        public void setGlobalVariable(int globalVariable) {
                this.globalVariable = globalVariable;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
                //reinitialize variable
        }
}
```

And in your Activity, do this,

```
(HelloApplication)getApplication()).setGlobalVariable(10);
int valiable=((HelloApplication)getApplication()).getGlobalVariable();
```

[Taken from here..](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/maintaining-global-application-state)

And speak about  SharedPreference, you should consider using them only when the value has to be stored for a long time. if not, you should make use of the Application class and use setters and getters which is the legitimate way to do this.

Comment: I think one problem is you have to do a cast everytime you want to access or modify a variable. Using a static class with statics methods/variables saves multiples casts and so process and memory, doesn't it ?

Comment: It is not necessary to cast every time if we store the casted object alone and make use of it through out..

Comment: It is a good idea, but I believe creating setters and getters each time I add a new variable is troublesome. However, I must have a look on advantages using Application extension.

Answer (score 5):

You can use SharedPreference to store flags and variables .

Look at this [Preference Demo](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/63.html) .

Comment: I need it only for a session time and I want the setting to reset on every new app launch.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Creating a Static class to save Global Variables, I would suggest you to use Application class.

see Link:

[Android global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable)

Answer (score 1):

use SharedPreference to store flags and variables

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

For Global variable:

it would be better to use the Android Application class. It's meant to store global application state

Answer (score 1):

i suggest that "never" use a global variables ....

when you are accessing to another activity you can throw some values using `Intent.putExtras(Name_parameter, "value_parameter")`

and to recive the value : `Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();` where b has all parameters

cheers,

Comment: The question is not about passing data from an activity to another, it's about accessing data whatever its nature from anywhere in the code.

Comment: Moreover, I meant generally in Java mentioning Android just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Well ! As far as I know It might depend on the size of your project ! If its relatively large its good to use separate class to store static data (not only one class , you might come in need of keeping them two or more classes depending on the type of the static data used)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should encapsulate your global class with a Singleton class. See more at 
[Singleton Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)