# Globally accessible objects - the most elegant way

Tags: java, android

Let's suppose I want to write an instant messenger client.
I guess there will be at least 2 activities:


UserManagerActivity - enables to manage accounts and logging in.
MainActivity - displaying contacts list etc.

But if I do it this way, there'll be some objects that should be accessible for both of them:

ConnectionManager - will be used for logging in, sending/receiving messages etc.
UserManager - holding information about users.
MusicPlayer - playing sounds.

So, what is the most elegant way to give both activities access to these objects?

I've heard about 4 possibilities:
- Using singleton pattern.
- Passing objects between activities using Bundle.
- Extending Application class.
- Using Service class (seems complicated to me).

1. Which option do you think is the best one?
2. Aren't globally accessible classes a sign of a bad project?
3. How can I learn to design elegant and efficient applications "skeletons"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Q: Aren't globally accessible classes a .. bad sign?"  A: No.  They are often the *ideal* solution.  I would consider using an Application class: [Android Global Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable).  Q: How can I learn to design elegant and efficient applications "skeletons"?  A: Study others' code.  And learn from your own successes and not-so-successes ;) IMHO...

Comment: Old joke: A guy gets into a cab in New York City and asks the cab driver, "How do I get to Carnegie Hall?"  The cabbie replies: "Practice, practice, practice".  Also applicable to programming, IMHO...

Answer (score 3):

Android created the Application class, if only in part, to handle this very case.  They guarantee that there will only ever be 1 instance of it.

http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html

Comment: Additionally, the easiest way is to keep a reference of an activity or both in the Application class, make public whatever members you are interested in and that's it :)