# Android App getting crashed when toggling between USB modes

Tags: android, usb

I am developing an Android application which involves displaying of Google Maps using **fragments**.

Here are the steps to reproduce the crash:

1. Start the application
2. Open the activity using fragments
3. Connect  Data cable
4. Switch USB mode to Mass storage
5. Resume the application
6. Application gets crashed

the Log for the crash is as follows:

```
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   start activity ComponentInfo{com.octanetech.cortes/com.octanetech.cortes.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at com.octanetech.cortes.MapActivity.displayPlaces(MapActivity.java:644)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at com.octanetech.cortes.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:158)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    ... 11 more
04-27 18:45:10.309: W/ActivityManager(2466):   Force finishing activity com.octanetech.cortes/.MapActivity
```

I am using Samsung Galaxy S device.

I am using static variables as global variables. I switched to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable) as well, but nothing helped. The entire class in which global variables are stored is getting killed. The interesting thing to note is that when I am following the same steps in the activities where there are no fragments, then my application is not getting crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your fragment state.

This can be done using "onSaveInstance" of the fragment

Also you can try setRetainInstance(true) for fragments.

When you toggle between USB modes, sometimes the Activity is recreated and hence the fragment.