# Save runtime data

Tags: android, global

How do I save data that I need in more than one Activities?
I'm not talking about saving it for different app-runs (I'd like to know this either), but
for the time the app is running.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities) and [this as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContentProviders are a great way of sharing data between two or more apps

check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) for the api

The other thing you asked (to share data between activities) is probably best achieved by using intents.  Something like this:

`Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("CONSTANT_TO_SHARE", constant_id);
    startActivity(intent)`