# How do I declare my ArrayAdapter GLOBAL?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I need to be able to access my listview's simpleadapter from an AsyncTask, so I was told I should declare the arrayAdapter as GLOBAL. How can I do that?

Please exemplify with code (that is what I understand best)

Thank you

Comment: make it static or create in the new class

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. I need to be able to access the adapter from the AsyncTask of a service. The adapter is declared now in an activity. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable except I do not need a simple variable but a adapter

Answer (score 0):

How any other varible...

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
   private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

      protected void onCreate(Bundle save) {
      super.onCreate(save);
      ....
       arrayAdapter = new...
   }

      class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
           protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           arrayAdapter...
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: By GLOBAL i mean GLOBAL in the application, not in the activity. So I need to access the adapter declared in activity XXXActivity, from a service on AsyncTask - postExecute