# Pass an object between activities

Tags: android

I made an app that has three activities, and it works like this:

```
Activity A --> Activity B --> Activity C
```

and for returning from activity C to activity A is like this :

```
Activity C --> Activity B --> Activity A
```

and I wanna to pass an object in `Activity C` to `Activity A`, but when I press back button or what ever, all of activity's objects has destroyed,and I can't receive the object on Activity A .How can I pass an object in `Activity C` to `Activity A`?

(I used DB for solving this problem already and when I am in activity C , I insert the object in a table and also use the table in activity A for getting the object . But I am looking for easier way to solve it)

please guide me...

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using multiple activity you can use multiple fragment in on activity.

Comment: I don't think exists an easy way to do it, anyway you could try to pass this object between the 3 activities and when you go back from activity C you pass it to B and B pass it to A. Or maybe something could be done using activity result... add more info about what you want to do.

Comment: you can use global variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) in `Activity C` as shown.

```
SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
data.edit().putString("somevalue", myvalue).commit();
```

and calling it in `Activity A` as:

```
SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
String myval= data.getString("somevalue","");
```

Comment: how can use this method for passing an object?

Answer (score 1):

You might override `onActivityResult` in your Activities A and B, so that B just takes the result back from the C and passes it back to A

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  switch(requestCode) {
     case (A) : {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // Extract the data returned from the Activity.
      }
      break;
    } 
  }
}
```

while in B and C you should pass back the object to the calling activity:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
// add your object here to the resultIntent
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is primitive data type, you can go with a SharedPreferences mechanism. You can also use some public static fields.

More information about your problem: http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3