# Passing extras to activity on backstack (on BACK press)

Tags: android

How can I pass extras to activity which is previous in backstack? When user press BACK button I would like to do something like:

```
intent.putExtra("playlist", playlist);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

I guess it has to be in *onStop()* method but how can I identify an activity that will be resumed? I found somthing like *getParentActivityIntent()* but I cannot understand documentation clearly and I do not know if it is what I need.

-----EDIT------

I will try to explain it other way.

in ActivityA I start a new ActivityB and pass some Extra:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
int var = 3;
intent.putExtra("var", var);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

in ActivityB I can do:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("var")) {
  var = getIntent().getIntExtra("var");
  var = var + 2;        
}
```

Now after pressing BACK button the user go back to ActivityA. Where *var = 3*. But I would like to pass the new value of var from ActivityB. I would like to have in ActivityA *var = 5*. How can I do this? I cannot find in documentation a reference to "previous" activity (in this case to ActivityA from ActivityB).

Comment: The code you've posted isn't clear. Where is it? In an `Activity` or in a `Fragment`?

Comment: It's in Activity. I use it normally when I start new activity. ex. after some action (choosing list item, clicking software button etc). Now I would like to do the same for phisical back button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you trying to do isn't possible, but you have at least two options.

Not use `startActivity`, but use `startActivityForResult` in ActivityA and override `onActivityResult`. In Activity B you will have to implement in `onBackPressed` something like this:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

More info: [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android)

Second option is to create shared variable during whole application (e.g. [by extend `android.app.Application` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable)). Set this varible in ActivityB and read in ActivityA.

Comment: It seems that it will be working (I used first solution). However I faced another problem so I have to solve it to be sure everything's ok with this one. Thanks anyway for your time!

Comment: It's OK, if it will help, please accept answer. Thanx.