# How to add two android:name attributes

Tags: android, sugarorm

My current AndroidManifest contain Sugar ORM declaration as follow

```
<application
    android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
```

as stated in their documentation at http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html. and it is included as jar library.

and now i need to add declaration for  a global variable as illustrated here  [Android global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable/1945297#1945297) which neeed to add

```
application android:name="MyApplication" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

to existing application section.
but this means two application sections or two "android:name" which is totally wrong. How to implement this scenario  of two applications parts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you need is just extends `com.orm.SugarApp` in your `MyApplication` class like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends com.orm.SugarApp {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
    }

    private String someVariable;

    public String getSomeVariable() {
        return someVariable;
    }

    public void setSomeVariable(String someVariable) {
        this.someVariable = someVariable;
    }
}
```

And the use your `MyApplication` in the manifest:

```
<application android:name="MyApplication" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: Is this true even SugarApp is a library from a JAR file. should i remove android:name="com.orm.SugarApp" and keep only  android:name="MyApplication"

Answer (score 3):

If u want to use sugar-orm and multidex both as android:name,u can refer below example.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import com.orm.SugarApp;

public class MyApplication extends SugarApp {
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

Here I extended MyApplication with com.orm.SugarApp and inside this Multidex is  installed  and next part is include MyApplication in android:name="MyApplication" in Application tag as shown below

```
<application
  ----------
  ----------
  android:name="MyApplication"/>
```