# Android Studio: Java- making a global variable

Tags: java, android, global-variables

How do you make a variable that can be used across the application. For example, in Swift, you can name it by:

```
    var formattedPrice: String = rowData["date"] as String
    defaults.setObject(rowData, forKey: "rowData")
```

and you can fetch it with:

```
    var variable = defaults.dictionaryForKey("rowData") as? NSDictionary
```

How can this behavior be mimicked in android studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable

Comment: I believe most of the answers on that post were Singletons. I don't think that is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you provided looks very similar to `SharedPreferences` in Android. `SharedPreferences` allow you to store data and access said data globally within your application. Here is a simple code snippet that shows you how to save and recall an `int`. You can save the variable as follows:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("your_preferences", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("your_integer_key", yourIntegerValue);
editor.commit();
```

And then retrieve it anywhere in your application like so:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("your_preferences", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
int myIntegerValue = sharedPreferences.getInt("your_integer_key", -1);
```

Comment: How could you do this with a string? And also how could this be printed out, like the println("print this"), as in swift?

Comment: Also where do SharedPreferences get placed? Under public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
?

Comment: Also why did you define the integer as -1 when you were trying to retrieve it? Shouldn't that be defined at the editor.putInt?

Comment: 1. You could do this with a `String` by using the appropriate methods, i.e. `.getString` for `SharedPreferences` and `.putString` for `SharedPreferences.Editor`. Then you would simply call something like `System.out.println(yourString)`. 2. `SharedPreferences` are stored in an XML file in the app data folder. 3. `-1` is just a random value. for all the `SharedPreferences` `.get` methods you have to specify a default value to be returned in the event that the requested preference does not exist.

Comment: can it go under app - value folder? Make a file example.xml , and put above inside?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can change the default location; why exactly would you want to do this?

Comment: I do not want to. I just do not know where the default location is.

Comment: Okay I gotcha. They are stored here: `data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml`