# How to provide the increment to textvale

Tags: android

I want to increase the textvalue automatic when the activity was reopen

for eq

when we order some food we got a order id which diffrent from pervious id

I want to do this in my project so any one help me

Comment: i fetch the value from textview. I want to increment it when the activity was reopend

Comment: store this value in sharedpreference

Answer (score 1):

Store value in SahredPrefrance and access or update when you order like following,

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("order_detail", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int old_amount=prefs.getInt("order_amount",0); // initial it return zero
        int new_amount=old_amount+currnt_amount;
        prefs.edit().putInt("order_amount",new_amount).commit();
```

Comment: Use a global variable concept to store the value and get it back...you can follow this example to get it done 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable