# Where to put app model

Tags: android

I am creating an Android app with several actions. I am using Volley to access a REST service to get data from a server.

Some of the data will be used across several actions, so there needs to be a central way of keeping the data objects (e.g. User).

Is there a pattern for Android to do so? Where would I put the model within the app structure and how would I access it from all actions?

Comment: Create a separate `package` and create `Class` name `User` with setter and getter methods..

Comment: But how would you get a reference to the User object? Use singleton?

Answer (score 0):

You can create global variables inside Application class 
Refer this :https://stackoverflow.com/a/1945297/3303075 
you can create own model class variable like "User" in-place of String and can be used throughout the app.