# How to pass data between activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities :Activity A and B.

I opened a webSockets in the Activity A,I will reveive the message at any time.However I want to show them in the Activity B(in the listView).But I donot konw how to pass the data which I just receive.Can any one help me?

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable

Comment: store it to local variable and use it whenver you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Comment: You can `getIntent` anywhere in the Activity. Why do you need the data before an Activity starts?

Answer (score 0):

## I want to get the data in Activity B anytime.So what should I do?

Can you please tell,how you can get data in activity B anytime?

Here,you can store your data in constant or share preferences and get at activity B whenever you require.

OR

If you want to get data from service then you can use broadcast receiver so you can receive data at activity B.

Comment: I opened a webSockets in Activity A, I will get the message at any time.and when I receive the message ,I want to show them in the LisiView (Whicn is at Activity B).

Comment: @JACKGAO in that case you should be using a service with a broadcast receiver and Activity B should be listening for that specific broadcast from your service to update it