# Google api is not connected in onConnected method

Tags: java, android, google-maps, localization

I am working on a new open source library, called Galileo, that helps developers using location api from Google in a single line.
However, when I resume my app, in OnConnected I get the exception that the client is not yet connected. The problem is, that using their methods, everything works fine, but I can't get to work my implementation. Here is what I got so far:

Galileo.java:

```
public class Galileo {
static volatile Galileo singleton;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;

Galileo (GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient, LocationListener locationListener){
    this.mGoogleApiClient = mGoogleApiClient;
    this.locationListener = locationListener;
}

public static Galileo with(@NonNull GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient, @NonNull  LocationListener locationListener ) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null || locationListener==null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("context == null");
    }
    if (singleton == null) {
        synchronized (Galileo.class) {
            if (singleton == null) {
                singleton = new Builder(mGoogleApiClient, locationListener).build();
            }
        }
    }
    return singleton;
}

public LocationRequest load(){
    return new LocationRequest(this);
}

LocationListener getLocationListener(){
    return this.locationListener;
}

GoogleApiClient getmGoogleApiClient(){
    return this.mGoogleApiClient;
}


public static class Builder {
    private final GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private final LocationListener locationListener;

    public Builder(@NonNull GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient, @NonNull LocationListener locationListener) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null || locationListener == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context must not be null.");
        }
        this.mGoogleApiClient = mGoogleApiClient;
        this.locationListener = locationListener;
    }



    /**
     * Toggle whether debug logging is enabled.
     * <p>
     * <b>WARNING:</b> Enabling this will result in excessive object allocation. This should be only
     * be used for debugging purposes. Do NOT pass {@code BuildConfig.DEBUG}.
     */


    public Galileo build() {
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = this.mGoogleApiClient;
        LocationListener locationListener = this.locationListener;
        return new Galileo(mGoogleApiClient, locationListener);
    }
}
}
```

LocationRequest.java:

```
public class LocationRequest {
private LocationListener locationListener;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private float mDistance;
private int mTime;
private int priority;
private boolean askForGPS;
private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

LocationRequest(Galileo galileo) {
    this.mGoogleApiClient = galileo.getmGoogleApiClient();
    this.locationListener = galileo.getLocationListener();
    this.mTime = 10000;
    this.priority = com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY;
    this.askForGPS = false;
}


public LocationRequest time(int mTime){
    this.mTime = mTime;
    return this;
}

public LocationRequest distance(float mDistance){
    this.mDistance = mDistance;
    return this;
}

public void go(){
    createLocationRequest();
    startLocationUpdates();
}

public void stop(){
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
    // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
    // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.

    // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
    // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationListener);
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
    // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
    System.out.print(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest , locationListener);
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest();

    // Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
    // inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
    // you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
    // requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(mTime);

    // Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
    // application will never receive updates faster than this value.
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(mTime/2);

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(priority);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    /*try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        //status.startResolutionForResult(MapsActivity.this, 1000);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }*/
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

and MapsActivity.java:

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    //createLocationRequest();
}


protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
    // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
    // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.

    // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
    // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
    // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    // Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
    // inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
    // you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
    // requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);

    // Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
    // application will never receive updates faster than this value.
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(
                                MapsActivity.this, 1000);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(48.162253, 17.0463122), 15));
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(48.162253, 17.0463122)).title("Hello Maps ");
    mMap.addMarker(marker);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            String imageURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location="+String.valueOf(marker.getPosition().latitude)+","+String.valueOf(marker.getPosition().longitude);
            Picasso.with(MapsActivity.this).load(imageURL).into(imageView);
            bottomSheetTextView.setText(marker.getTitle());
            currentMarker = marker;
            Geocoder geocoder;
            List<Address> addresses;
            String address;
            geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
                address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                address = "";
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            addressView.setText(address);
            return false;
        }
    });
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            if (behavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike.STATE_HIDDEN);
            }
            currentMarker = null;
        }
    });
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Hello Maps ");
            mMap.addMarker(marker);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    String[] LOCATION_PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
    Permission.PermissionBuilder permissionBuilder =
            new Permission.PermissionBuilder(LOCATION_PERMISSIONS, 1000, new Permission.PermissionCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(int i) {
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(int i) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionAccessRemoved(int i) {

                }
            });
    requestAppPermissions(permissionBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Within {@code onPause()}, we pause location updates, but leave the
    // connection to GoogleApiClient intact.  Here, we resume receiving
    // location updates if the user has requested them.

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Galileo.with(mGoogleApiClient,this).load().go();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Stop location updates to save battery, but don't disconnect the GoogleApiClient object.
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Galileo.with(mGoogleApiClient,this).load().stop();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if(mLastLocation!=null){
        Log.d("Lat, lon", String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()) + " ," + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()), 15));
    }
    //Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
    Galileo.with(mGoogleApiClient,this).load().go();}
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(mLastLocation==null){
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 15));
    }
    mLastLocation = location;
    Log.d("Lat, lon", String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()) + " ," + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()), 15));
}
```

Comment: when you come back gain then your `mGoogleApiClient` is not initialized, because when you come back then activity is not restart but only resume so it's onResume() method is called. I suggest you that you initialize that instance in app level and use that single object to all activity in your project.

Comment: Can you please show me how to improve my code ? Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable ?

Comment: Hmmm yes. But thank you. Meanwhile I solved my problem. Not sure if it haven't actually created another bug but it works. I will post my solution as soon as possible