# Passing data from an activity back to recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I pass data from an Activity back to the RecyclerView adapter. I've clicked one of the row in the recycler view and started a new activity. From the new activity how can I pass an object back to adapter and update the row from where I've started the activity

```
    public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Movie> moviesList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, year, genre;
        LinearLayout layout;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
            layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        }
    }

    public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
        holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());
        holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, MovieDetailsActivity.class));   
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }
}
```

From the new Activity I've created I'll edit the movie details and once clicked OK I need to pass the Movie object back to adapter and update the corresponding row.

Comment: hey buddy, share your codes and clarify your question regarding what you want to achieve such as how you want the row to be updated...

Comment: I think the question has clearly explained @TRIENTRAN

Comment: you pass the object to db not to the adapter,how do you edit the object anyway?simply put it in edittext

Comment: take a look at the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130535/android-blog-app-should-i-use-sharedpreferences-or-intents/50140381#50140381

Comment: @D.'s I don't want to save. I need get from Movie object and then update the row.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, first of all you need to implement a method to add an element in your adapter, let's say `void addItem(Movie movie);`

Then, you need to get your data back from your previous activity.

There you have multiple solution. The most obvious one, given the code you've shown us would be to make your `Movie` class `Parcelable`. When your movie has been extended to `Parcelable` I'll just give you [this](http://www.parcelabler.com/) link as I'm not the best person to explain Parcelables to you :/) you will be able to bundle it to your `activity`.

So, you have your adapter in your first activity (we will call it `MainActivity`) and you want to add a `Movie` from your second activity (let's call it `SecondActivity`)
What you'll need to do is open your `SecondActivity` "for result" which mean that you're expecting a result coming from this activity.

Once in your `SecondActivity` do whatever logic you need to have a new `Movie` to add and return it to your `MainActivity` by putting it in your result.

Here is a link about [activities and results](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Your final code will look like something like this

MainActivity

```
public static String MOVIE_REQUEST = "movie_request";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
     ...
        previous logic
     ...

     recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

     ...
        rest of the logic of your activity
     ...
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MOVIE_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Movie movie = (Movie)data.getParcelableExtra(SecondActivity.MOVIE_EXTRA);
            mAdapter.addItem(movie);
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public void addItem(Movie movie){
    movieList.add(movie);
    //Your code should be way better than this anwser btw) notifyDatasetChanged isn't the best way to proceed
    notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

SecondActivity

```
public static final String MOVIE_EXTRA = "movie_extra";
private void sendMovie(Movie movie){
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(MOVIE_EXTRA, movie);
    //At this point you're returning your result to your first activity
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
}
```

And you're done, you should have gotten a new movie from your second activity

Regards,
Matthieu

Comment: Hello, I just came across this answer and I think this is what I was looking for for days :)
The only thing that I don't quite understand is, what do we do with the method ```public void sendMovie(Movie movie)``` ? Since it is a private method, it can only be used inside the same class. But where do we have to use it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `boolean` in your model name it `isSelected`, once clicked on that object make it `true`, and in `onBindView` method of `RecyclerView` make a check if object `isSelected` is true then perform selected action as you want to display.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
        holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());
        if(movie.isSelected()){
        holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
        holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        movie.setSelected(true);
                        notifyDatasetChanged();
                        mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, MovieDetailsActivity.class));   
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

declare your adapter activity singleTask in manifest and then when you  open new activity from adapter on click of item, pass the int position of item in second activity, then in second activity call first activity using intent like this:

```
 public void callFirst()
{
Intent intent =new Intent(this, FirstAdatperActivity.classs);
// pass position which we was bring from first activity...
intent.putExtra("position", position);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
}
```

then you will get result in onNewIntent() method you can override in your first activity and get intent data position and refresh adapter

```
recentAdapter.notifyItemChanged(postion, object);
```

in other way you can call second activity using this:

```
Intent intent =new Intent(this, SecondActvity.class);
intent,putExtra("pos",postion);
startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
```

and from second activity

```
Intent intent =new Intent(this, SecondActvity.class);
intent,putExtra("pos",postion);
setresult(101);
```

then you will get response in onActivityResult with position in intent bundle data , so you cal refresh your adapter from there.