# inputStream null delay Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hi there I'm writing a client app in android studio

this is my client class:

```
class Client : Socket()
{

    init {
        recvMessage()
    }

    companion object
    {
        var receivedMessage :ByteArray = ByteArray(1024)
    }


    fun sendMessage(data: ByteArray )
    {
        if(isConnected)
            Thread {
                val dataOutputStream = DataOutputStream(this.outputStream)
                dataOutputStream.write(data)
            }.start()
    }



    private fun recvMessage() = Thread{
        while(true)
        {
            if (isConnected) {
                inputStream.read(receivedMessage)
            }
        }
    }.start()

    fun getMessage():ByteArray
    {
        return receivedMessage;
    }

}
```

To use this client  I have MyApplication class as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable)

In the app startup the client get configured (connects to server)

then I move to login activity  there I send a login request to the server  and get an answer 
this is the login button function

```
fun login(view: View)
{
        val username = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username).text.toString()
        val password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password).text.toString()

        (this.application as MyApplication).client.sendMessage(PacketFactory.loginRequest(username, password))
        val serverResponse = (this.application as MyApplication).client.getMessage()
        val buf : ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(serverResponse)

        println()
        println("got:" + Message.getRootAsMessage(buf).data)
        println()


}
```

The problem is that at the first click I get null then the msg I needed before (a click before)

Any help for those more experienced would be most appreciated. I'm at the end of my skills here... need some guidance, please!

Comment: Of course. You start a thread to send and receive a message. But before the thread has send or received a message you already try to read a received message. There is nothing received yet. That is normal uding threads.

Comment: Your sendMessage function also tries to receive a message. Quite confusing name.

Comment: @blackapps I have changed it still nothing

Comment: recvMessage() is not called anymore.

Comment: @blackapps recvMessage() called in init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed:
I added messages stack

```
package com.trivia_app
import java.io.DataOutputStream
import java.net.Socket
import java.util.*

class Client : Socket()
{

    init {
        recvMessage()
    }

    companion object
    {
        var pendingMessages : Stack<ByteArray> = Stack()
    }


    fun sendMessage(data: ByteArray )
    {
        if(isConnected)
            Thread {
                val dataOutputStream = DataOutputStream(this.outputStream)
                dataOutputStream.write(data)
            }.start()
    }



    private fun recvMessage() = Thread{
        val message = ByteArray(1024)
        while(true)
            if (isConnected)
                if (inputStream.read(message) > 0)
                    pendingMessages.push(message)
    }.start()

    fun getMessage():ByteArray
    {
        while (pendingMessages.empty());
        return pendingMessages.pop()
    }

}
```