# Passing an ArrayList or creating a new one?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-intent, initializing

I'm building an application in which I create the same ArrayList in every Activity. An other option is creating the ArrayList in the first Activity and then pass it on to other activities. However, I don't know if this is 'better' than creating the same ArrayList every time. I know by creating a new ArrayList it would take up a bit of memory (ArrayList is not so big), but passing an ArrayList by using an Intent slows your app down, right?

What's the best option to go with?

With kind regards,
Koen

Comment: passing array list. You will not be passing actual arraylist, it will be the reference always.

Comment: `but passing an ArrayList by using an Intent slows your app down, right?` if this were the case, why would google still be allowing it to be done ? if it was that bad, wouldn't it have been deprecated by now ? you're trying to do premature optimization here, realistically, none of this will make a difference. choose what makes the most sense for you

Comment: `it will be the reference always` No. @Pirate. First the list is copied to the intent. Then at receiving side the list is extracted from the intent. There are then three complete lists in memory.

Comment: i commented with respect to java lists. @bla

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make an `ArrayList` in custom `Application` class and use it in every `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to provide the Arraylist system wide?

For example this could be an option: [Android global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Arraylist in java are the reference variable so passing an arrayList is better approach than creating every time, unless you don't have any write operation on it, otherwise it will give you inconsistency result,